# Android get contacts getting really long when multiple Google accounts are connected to phone

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

maybe somone knows solution how to get phone contacts only from main google account, not all of them, otherwise it takes ages to load.
Here is the code that I am using:

```
  private val projectionForPhoneNumber by lazy {
        arrayOf(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
        )
    }
    private val projectionForNames by lazy {
        arrayOf(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME
        )
    }
    private val phoneNoPattern = "[()\\s-]+".toRegex()

  context.contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projectionForPhoneNumber, null, null, null
            )?.use { phoneCursor ->
                phoneCursor.apply {
                    while (moveToNext()) {
                        try {
                            val contactId = getString(getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID))
                            val nameQuery = "${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE} = ? " +
                                "AND ${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID} = $contactId"

                            val nameQueryParams =
                                arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)

                            context.contentResolver.query(
                                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                projectionForNames,
                                nameQuery,
                                nameQueryParams,
                                null
                            )?.use { nameCursor ->
                                mapPhoneContact(contacts, nameCursor)
                            }
                        } catch (exception: Exception) {
                            exceptionsLogger.logError(exception)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            val collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
            contacts.values
                .sortedWith { first, second -> collator.compare(first.name, second.name) }
                .sortedBy { first -> first.name.firstOrNull()?.isLetter() == false }
```